# enviar notificação push quando feed for alterado

Tags: firebase, webview, push-notification, android-webview

preciso enviar a notificação push para ususario de meu app, é um webview com feed de alguns blogs, e quando esse feed(rss) for alterado ele automaticamente envia uma notificação aos usuarios.

Comment: Cara, na boa, eu como usuário final, não como desenvolvedor, iria achar um saco ter que ficar receber várias notificações praticamente num período de tempo talvez, eu digo talvez, curto. Só uma sugestão, tente enviar no máximo 1 notificação por dia, porém mostrando várias  postagens nesta mesma notificação. Se você fizer desta forma que está querendo, certeza que depois do 3º dia de instalação do app, a pessoa já irá desinstalar. Então talvez não seja interessante pra você. PS. É só meu ponto de vista.

Comment: ineressante usa sugestao, porem preciso ainda um tuto ou dica de como fazer, mesmo que seja uma por dia,